# Meteor/Iron-router subroute to different meteor application

Tags: meteor, nginx, url-routing, iron-router

I have two meteor applications. One is a fairly complex job management application (application 1), and the other is more or less a feature for application 1 that was built as an internal mvp to test out the feature (application 2). Now I need to integrate application 2 into application 1, but the problem I have is there are several conflicting packages being used between the two applications: application 1 = iron:router+blaze+custom CSS, application 2 = flowrouter+react+ionic.

To handle these issues with conflicting packages, I would like to set up the second application on a separate server, but keep it under the same domain as the first application. I also would prefer that application 2 lives under a subdirectory (/application2), as opposed to a subdomain.

Is there a good way to do this without dealing with setting up a reverse proxy, such as nginx? Basically, I want my meteor application 1 to connect or route to the new server for application 2 anytime the user clicks on a link to the /application2 subdomain, and then application 2 routes back to application 1 anytime a link to any other subdirectory is clicked. Thanks.

Comment: nginx is going to be _way_ easier than trying to do this in Meteor.

Comment: The problem is I don't really know much about nginx. I think what I will end up doing is putting the second application in a package, which should eliminate the namespacing issues.